# How to disable autoscroll for url with # anchor name : AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have included `autoscroll` attribute in my `ui-view` so that whenever a new view (page) is loaded than it automatically scrolls to top. However, I want to add an exception to this in such a manner that the url with anchor name for ex. `page1#section2` the page should not auto scroll.

Here is the code snippet for your understanding.

index.html

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <header>
        <top-navi></top-navi>
    </header>
    <ui-view autoscroll></ui-view>  
</div>
</body>
```

one of the template code

```
<a ui-sref="portfolios" ></a>
<!-- Equivalent to calling /portfolios. Here page auto scrolls as expected-->
<a ui-sref="portfolios({'#': 'id1'})" >Explore</a>
<!-- Equivalent to calling /portfolios#id1 Here the page should not auto scroll-->
```

Can anyone tell me how this can be achieved using AngularJS 1.x in the most simplest manner.